# How to observe a simple float in Java?

Tags: java, javafx, binding, observable

I have a JavaFX Application based on vlcj and I want to observe or bind a float.

```
float position = mediaPlayer.getPosition(); // returns actual position
```

How can I observe or bind position to a slider? Position has no property.

```
Slider timeSlider = new Slider(0d, 100d, 0d);
timeSlider.setValue(position); // but position is permanently changing
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: And how exactly do you receive values from `mediaPlayer.getPosition()`. I think you can simply change slider values directly there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a binding here, but:

As I can see in [`MediaPlayer`](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.10.1/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/MediaPlayer.html#addMediaPlayerEventListener-uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerEventListener-), you can add listeners:

```
void addMediaPlayerEventListener(MediaPlayerEventListener listener);
```

and [`MediaPlayerEventListener`](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.10.1/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/MediaPlayerEventListener.html#positionChanged-uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayer-float-) class has a

`void positionChanged(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, float newPosition);` method which class is implemented by [`MediaPlayerEventAdapter`](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.10.1/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/MediaPlayerEventAdapter.html).

> Media play-back position changed.

Therefore this two way listening should work:

```
mediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void positionChanged(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, float newPosition) {
        timeSlider.setValue(newPosition);
    }
});

timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldval, newval) -> mediaPlayer.setPosition(newval));
```

(Haven't tried it)

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I will try it now.

Comment: timeSlider.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(Event event) {
    if (player.getMp().isPlaying()) {
     player.getMp().setPosition((float) (timeSlider.getValue() / 100));
    }
   }
  });

Comment: player.getMp().addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void positionChanged(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, float newPosition) {
    timeSlider.setValue(newPosition * 100);
   }
  });

Comment: Yes, I had to change little things. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear. Happy media-playing! ;)

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/alibranic/vpfx/commits/7ebbf04442a380ff4564fbd41957d61366a4f13f

Comment: Please bear in mind that all media player events originate on a *native* thread and will *not* be delivered to your application on the UI event thread.